# if-else with list-like true/false arguments

Tags: r

Is there an elegant way to simplify this call?

```
a <- list(1, 2, 3)
b <- list(4, 5)
conditional = TRUE
if (conditional) {
  x <- a
} else {
  x <- b
}

x
# [1, 2, 3]
```

I've tried `x <- ifelse(TRUE, a, b)`, but it assumes the conditional is a vector which must be iterated, so in this case it returns a single value (in this case, `1`).

dplyr's `if_else`, on the other hand, demands that the lists be of equal length. And even if they were, it also iterates through the conditional and would also output a single value `1`.

So, is there some clean way of solving this or is the simple if{}else{} the way to go?

Comment: Three errors here. 1) do NOT use "=" for "==", and 2) you probably don't want "==" anyway but rather want the set-containment operator `%in%`, and any test of TRUE will always go to the first alternative, so using code to request a fix withou describing the problem is the fundamental error.

Comment: @42- I think OP wants to create new object `x` based on some condition. If condition is `TRUE` then `x <- a` else `x <- b`.

Comment: @42-, shree is correct. The condition is basically irrelevant. What I want is that if the single condition (it is a single boolean) is true, `x <- a`, otherwise `x <- b`. I don't want `x` to be a list which contains `a` or `b`, nor do I want to iterate over the values of the conditional to get the respective values from `a` or `b` (since there's only one value in the conditional).

Comment: So what DO you want? Saying what you do not want after offering only failing code is continuing to leave this question unclear, hence my vote to close on that basis.

Comment: @42- I have offered working code. It's the code at the top of the post, using a standard if-else statement. I'm looking for a one-liner which mimics that code's behavior: given a single conditional, assign a variable as equal to the entirety of one of two lists.

Comment: You essentially offered a one-liner. Sure it had line breaks for the human brain, but R pretty much ignores line breaks  and other white-space in code. Is this supposed to solve some sort of problem?

Comment: What about `x <- if (conditional) a else b`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple one-liner using `switch`.

```
x <- switch(TRUE + 1, b, a)
x

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

x <- switch(FALSE + 1, b, a)
x

[[1]]
[1] 4

[[2]]
[1] 5
```

This uses the `switch` behavior with integer `EXPR` as described in documentation -

> switch works in two distinct ways depending whether the first argument
>   evaluates to a character string or a number.
>
> If the value of EXPR is not a character string it is coerced to
>   integer. Note that this also happens for factors, with a warning, as
>   typically the character level is meant. If the integer is between 1
>   and nargs()-1 then the corresponding element of ... is evaluated and
>   the result returned: thus if the first argument is 3 then the fourth
>   argument is evaluated and returned.